# Extract title with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this

```
from urllib import request
url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election-us-2016-35791008"
html = request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
html[:60]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
raw = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').get_text()
raw.find_all('title', limit=1)
print (raw.find_all("title"))
'<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN'
```

I want to extract the title of the page using BeautifulSoup but getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Passanova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    raw.find_all('title', limit=1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Please any suggestions

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To navigate the soup, you need a BeautifulSoup object, not a string. So  remove your `get_text()` call to the soup.

Moreover, you can replace `raw.find_all('title', limit=1)` with `find('title')` which is equivalent.

Try this :

```
from urllib import request
url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election-us-2016-35791008"
html = request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
html[:60]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find('title')

print(title) # Prints the tag
print(title.string) # Prints the tag string content
```

Comment: Some websites include the domain in the title tag like 'My title - My website'. If I don't want that, is there a better option than to just chop off everything after the - ? I don't want to assume there will never be a title that includes a dash.

Comment: You should ask another question for that but you could try a regex to remove all characters before last `-` : `re.sub('.*- *', '', title.string)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866238/how-to-grab-accurate-titles-from-web-pages-without-including-site-data

Comment: I wonder, what is this `html[:60]` supposed to do? :)

Comment: @BeryCZ It's a slice of `html` value (the `60` first chars). But it's useless here (just copy/paste from OP code).

Comment: @SLePort yea I know it doesn't really do anything here :) Might just "print" something in a shell

Answer (score 11):

You can directly use "soup.title" instead of "soup.find_all('title', limit=1)" or "soup.find('title')" and it'll give you the title.

```
from urllib import request
url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election-us-2016-35791008"
html = request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
html[:60]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title
print(title)
print(title.string)
```

Answer (score 5):

Make it simple as that:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlString, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title.text
```

Here, **soup.title** returns a **BeautifulSoup element** which is the title element.

Answer (score 1):

In some pages I had the NoneType problem. A suggestion is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
if (soup.title is not None):
    title = soup.title.string
```