# How to grab accurate titles from web pages without including site data

Tags: python

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956045/extract-title-with-beautifulsoup/35956388#comment111155595_35956388) [and a few others] which talks a bit about BeautifulSoup for reading html. It mostly does what I want, grabs a title for a webpage.

```
def get_title(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    if len(html) > 0:
        contents = BeautifulSoup(html)
        title = contents.title.string
        return title
    return None
```

The issue that I run into is that sometimes articles will come back with metadata attached at the end with " - some_data". A good example is [this link](https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/53373542) to a BBC Sport article which reports the title as

> Jack Charlton: 1966 England World Cup winner dies aged 85 - BBC Sport

I could do something simple like cut off anything after the last '-' character

```
title = title.rsplit(', ', 1)[0]
```

But that assumes that any meta exists after a "-" value. I don't want to assume that there will never be an article who's title ends in " - part_of_title"

I found the [Newspaper3k library](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but it's definitely more than I need - all I need is to grab a title and ensure that it's the same as what the user posted. My friend who pointed me to Newspaper3k also mentioned it could be buggy and didn't always find titles correctly, so I would be inclined to use something else if possible.

My current thought is to continue using BeautifulSoup and just add on [fuzzywuzzy](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python) which would honestly also help with slight misspellings or punctuation differences. But, I would certainly prefer to start from a place that included comparing against accurate titles.

Comment: You already have the accurate title. That title was chosen by the creator of the website. If you want to take only thre *relevant part* of the title, that requires defining what is relevant. Even a human would be unable to do that reliably for every page, let alone a computer. What you could do is detect that a part (begining or the end) of many pages is always the same and remove that part.

Comment: It's not consistent across sites, so I wouldn't have a pattern necessarily. But, while I might have an 'accurate' title, the title a user sees when clicking on a link does not include that title. What I want is the title a user would see when they open the link

Answer (score 1):

Here is how reddit handles getting title data.

https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/blob/40625dcc070155588d33754ef5b15712c254864b/r2/r2/lib/utils/utils.py#L255

```
def extract_title(data):
    """Try to extract the page title from a string of HTML.
    An og:title meta tag is preferred, but will fall back to using
    the <title> tag instead if one is not found. If using <title>,
    also attempts to trim off the site's name from the end.
    """
    bs = BeautifulSoup(data, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
    if not bs or not bs.html.head:
        return
    head_soup = bs.html.head

    title = None

    # try to find an og:title meta tag to use
    og_title = (head_soup.find("meta", attrs={"property": "og:title"}) or
                head_soup.find("meta", attrs={"name": "og:title"}))
    if og_title:
        title = og_title.get("content")

    # if that failed, look for a <title> tag to use instead
    if not title and head_soup.title and head_soup.title.string:
        title = head_soup.title.string

        # remove end part that's likely to be the site's name
        # looks for last delimiter char between spaces in strings
        # delimiters: |, -, emdash, endash,
        #             left- and right-pointing double angle quotation marks
        reverse_title = title[::-1]
        to_trim = re.search(u'\s[\u00ab\u00bb\u2013\u2014|-]\s',
                            reverse_title,
                            flags=re.UNICODE)

        # only trim if it won't take off over half the title
        if to_trim and to_trim.end() < len(title) / 2:
            title = title[:-(to_trim.end())]

    if not title:
        return

    # get rid of extraneous whitespace in the title
    title = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', title, flags=re.UNICODE)

    return title.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: Faced the same issue. Thanks for the code; this was very helpful!