# Empty return when trying to get title attriubute in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the names of programming languages from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages).

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'div-col'}):
    for b in a.find_all('li'):
        print(b["title"])
```

When I try to print it, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'title'.
```

How else is it possible to get the value of the title attribute? I saw on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956045/extract-title-with-beautifulsoup) that my method was the way to do it. But in my case it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

You grab all the `<li>` and try to print a `title`, but `<li>` do not have a `title`

It is the `<a>` that contains a `title`, so print:

```
print(b.a["title"])
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'div-col'}):
    for b in a.find_all('li'):
        print(b.a["title"])
```

**Output**

```
A Sharp (.NET)
A-0 System
A+ (programming language)
ABAP
ABC (programming language)
ABC ALGOL
ACC (programming language)
Accent (programming language)
Distributed Application Specification Language
Action! (programming language)
ActionScript
Actor (programming language)
...
```

### Alternativ

To avoid the second loop use [css selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select('div.div-col  li  a'):
    print(a['title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here b is returning `li` tag with `a` tag. so to catch the `title` use `b.a` then title text.

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'div-col'}):
    for b in a.find_all('li'):
        print(b.a.text)
```