# Print specified text from .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

im a beginner with python, I wrote a simple webscraper script which returned a html code and printed it into the output2.txt file, and I need to print out thats behind "title=", but I cant seem to do so.

I tried .find method which returned the list of indexes, now I'm stuck at how to print the text starting from the indexes in the list, if it's even possible

Here's the code:

```
with open('output2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    output = []
    for line in f:
        titles = line.find("title")
        if titles >= 0:
            output.append(titles)

output.sort()
print(output)
```

As I said I don't know if its even possible to do this, please be kind.

I'll be glad for any advice,

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What does `output2.txt` look like?

Comment: I don't know if i can post this here, it contains a lot of text @Dash

Comment: Just post a couple of lines, including one that has the `title` in it

Comment: Where is your webscraping script? What package or module did you use to do the web-scraping? It likely contains something that would make this task a lot easier than re-reading the output from file. Or you could possibly use the same module to interpret the html and find the title a lot easier than with a blunt string search.

Comment: <li><a href="/wiki/Kurilsk%C3%BD_bobtail" title="Kurilský bobtail">Kurilský bobtail dlouhosrstý</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Kurilsk%C3%BD_bobtail" title="Kurilský bobtail">Kurilský bobtail krátkosrstý</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Kymersk%C3%A1_ko%C4%8Dka" title="Kymerská kočka">Kymerská kočka</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Mansk%C3%A1_ko%C4%8Dka" title="Manská kočka">Manská kočka</a></li>

Comment: @Grismar Modules: requests, beautifulsoup

Comment: BeautifulSoup has all you need for a fairly simple solution, as evidenced here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956045/extract-title-with-beautifulsoup - all you need is to load the page from file instead of from a web request, but that's trivial?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SO answer: [Extract title with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956045/extract-title-with-beautifulsoup)

Copying from that answer, it looks like you should be doing something like

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = ""
with open('output2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title
print(title)
print(title.string)
```

Comment: I'll try this tommorow, I'm dead tired rn, thanks for helping me :)